# SSRS creating subtotal based on condition

Tags: sql, reporting-services, conditional-statements

I'm using SSRS 2008 and currently doing this matrix table. My table will populate all the days in a month, from Monday to Sunday. What I need is to add a subtotal row everytime it passes Sunday to sum up the total amount for the week.

```
               Amount
Monday           100
Tuesday          200
Wednesday        200
Thursday         100 
Friday           100
Saturday         300
Sunday           100
**Week 1 Total    1100   <-----Add in this subtotal row each time after Sunday**
Monday           100
Tuesday          200
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add week number into query and group the matrix using this field.

Your dataset should look like:

```
WeekNo | Day |  Amount
1 | Monday           100
1 | Tuesday          200
1 | Wednesday        200
1 | Thursday         100 
1 | Friday           100
1 | Saturday         300
1 | Sunday           100
2 | Monday           100
2 | Tuesday          200
...
.
```

Then use WeekNo as grouping expression and display subtotals.

Comment: Ok, now my dataset is set that way already. But how to create as grouping expression? If I choose Add Totals, it would add up the total amount for every day.

Comment: 1) Create matrix, 2)add WeekNo into rows, 3) Down in Row groups section right click on WeekNo and add child group, grouped by Day, 4) add amount in the data part of matrix, 5) Right click on Day group in Row groups section, and add total. And that's it.